# Load csv into mysql using Python syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have a TSV file with the following structure:

```
#DAteTime    Userid    tweet (each separated by \t)
2009-06-07 02:07:41 http://twitter.com/hokiepokie728    @fabro84 'Before the Storm' is a new song from the Jonas Brothers that is going to be on their new album. miley has a duet with nick on it!
2009-06-07 02:07:42 'http://twitter.com/annieng'    is in LA now
```

How can I import this file into a MySQL table called `tweet` with python? I have the following table structure:

```
1   DT  datetime
2   USER    varchar(141)    
3   TWEET   varchar(141)    
4   ID  bigint(20)          AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: Well, the file size is around 3 GB. The query that am trying is:
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","", "TWEETS" )
sql = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'sample.txt' INTO TABLE tweet FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\' ESCAPED BY '\\' (DT,USER,TWEET)"""
cursor = db.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute(str(MySQLdb.escape_string(sql)))
    #cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    db.rollback()
    logging.warn("Failed to insert values ")
db.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with mysql-connector-python 1.2.2 you can do it like this

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.constants import ClientFlag

cnx = mysql.conector.connect(client_flags=[ClientFlag.LOCAL_FILES], ....)

cur = cnx.cursor()
cur.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '</path/to/data/file>' INTO "
            "TABLE tweet")
```